# How do I show that the Space X is not complete

Tags: latex

```
Let $X= C[-3,3]$ with\\
 
$||f||_{2}= \int_{-2}^{2}|f(t)| $\\
show that X is not complete.
```

I tried to draw the graph but I think I am not getting it right. With the graph, I can get the sequence, and it can make the whole work easier.